# how to stop Ansible task successfully, not failing?

Tags: break, ansible

I've searched for examples on how to stop execution of an Ansible task without failing it.

A straightforward example:

```
- name: check file
  stat: path={{some_path}}
  register: check_file_result

- name: if file exists, stop
  **fail**: msg="file exists, stopping"
  when: check_file_result.stat.exists
```

This works as in it stops the execution, but fails with tons of red flavoured text *probably* stopping whole playbook from running further tasks. Is there a way to stop the execution as if all of it ended with "OK"?

Note: Workaround is to simply add "when: check_file_result.stat.exists == false", but this scales very poorly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If there are multiple tasks you don't want to execute when `check_file_result.stat.exists` then I would probably encapsulate all those tasks in a separate file and then conditionally [`include`](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html#task-include-files-and-encouraging-reuse) that file, e.g.

```
- name: check file
  stat: path={{ some_path }}
  register: check_file_result

- include: file_ops.yml
  when: check_file_result.stat.exists
```

Example directory structure:

```
|- roles/
  |- foo
    |- tasks
      |- main.yml
      |- file_ops.yml
    |- vars
      |- main.yml
```

Using this method is DRY :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot accept it more. This is brilliant, simple and elegant at the same time. Thanks!

Comment: Nowadays I think we could also use a `block`.